# How can I destroy fineuploader instance and create a new using jquery?

Tags: fine-uploader

I have one dropdown above file uploader button and wants to upload to S3 if dropdown's value is audio or video and wants to upload to my server if dropdown's value is pdf, doc, or ppt. How can I implement this?

```
$( '#fileType').change(function() {
    lessonType = $('#fileType').val();
    if(lessonType == 'audio' || lessonType == 'video') {
       $('#fileupload').fineUploaderS3(...);
    } else {
       $('#fileupload').fineUploader(...);
    } 
})
```

Above is not working so thought to delete instance before assigning fineuploader or fineuploaderS3. Please let me know how can I destroy fineuploader instance.

Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my answer below to show that you should reset the instances to clear events as well.

Comment: For future readers of this question - I would strongly suggest you simply _not_ use the jQuery wrapper for Fine Uploader. Fine Uploader by itself contains all documented features and the wrapper does not add any. There is no reason that I can think of to use jQuery in this context. Read more at https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/1310.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are not adding extra elements associated with a specific uploader, then you can use `$("#fileupload").empty()`  to remove the uploader's DOM stuff from the page before rendering/instantiating the other instance of the uploader.

```js
$( '#fileType').change(function() {
    lessonType = $('#fileType').val();
    if(lessonType == 'audio' || lessonType == 'video') {
       $('#fileupload').reset();
       $('#fileupload').empty();
       $('#fileupload').fineUploaderS3(...);
    } else {
       $('#fileupload').reset();
       $('#fileupload').empty();
       $('#fileupload').fineUploader(...);
    } 
});
```

([jQuery's `empty()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/empty/))

Comment: what if fineuploader was created by `s3Uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploader`

Answer (score 1):

I just had to do this and, in my case, .reset() did not exist to clear events.  I was able to do just use jquery's `.unbind()` and that worked just fine:

`$('#fine-uploader').unbind().empty()`